# Pass few arguments into a batch file from C#

Tags: c#, forms, batch-file

I have this batch file:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central\130\RoleTailored Client\finsql.exe" Command=ExportToNewSyntax, File=%1.%5.txt, Database=%2, ServerName=%3, Filter=Type=%4; ID=%5
pause
```

For some parameters, I created text fields for dynamic fill forms (*but now I use string variables for an example*).

Code which I use for set parameters:

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myBat = @"C:\NAV.bat";

    string _PathtoSourceObject = @"D:\ConvertToExtentions\CAL\";
    string _DataBase = @"Demo Database NAV (13-0)NA";
    string _ServerName = @"testserver";
    string _TypeObject = "table";
    string _IDObject = "22";

    Process process = new Process();

    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"{3}\" \"{4}\"", _PathtoSourceObject, _DataBase, _ServerName, _TypeObject, _IDObject);
    process.StartInfo.FileName = myBat;

    process.Start();
}
```

The problem is that I get just an empty console window.

Can you explain what I missed?

Comment: Stream the error output so you can see what's wrong `StreamReader reader = process.StandardError; Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());`

Comment: Batch files are text files not programs and are run by CMD.exe. You've used `ShellExecute=False` saying don't use file extensions, nor is there a reason too as that is taking a dependency on how the user has configured their system. EG: Some IT departments change batch from being run by default to being edited by default. Type `cmd /?` NB: You MUST use `/c` or `/k` at least.

Comment: You also can't `CD` to a program. Remove `cd`. Type `CD /?`

Comment: Is `ServerName=%3, Filter=Type=%4; ID=%5` on a new line in your actual [tag:batch-file]? or is it an error in your question which needs fixing?

Comment: The console window with no text output is expected. You are redirecting the *Stdout* and *Stderr* streams. Typically, the C# program will read the redirected streams and the console window can be hidden, as a console window with no text is useless to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you run the exe file directly? 
As you've done, but with the fully qualified executable filename instead:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("Command=ExportToNewSyntax File=\"{0}\" Database=\"{1}\" ServerName=\"{2}\" Filter=\"{3}\" Type=\"{4}\"", _PathtoSourceObject, _DataBase, _ServerName, _TypeObject, _IDObject);
process.StartInfo.FileName = exeFile; // full qualified name here
```

And after starting the process, add these lines so you get the output and eventual errors:

```
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```